# Internet Explorer 11 and earlier - does not respond to CSS column styling

Tags: multiple-columns, internet-explorer-11

I wonder if anyone has a fix for a small problem.  Internet Explorer 11 does not respond to a simple CSS which creates columns on webpage.  The text flows across the whole page and does not flow into columns. I am using a simple HTML and CSS solution - no scripting.

The CSS is as follows

```
.two-col {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 15px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap : 15px;
    -moz-column-rule-color: #888;
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
    -webkit-column-rule-color: #888;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
    -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Go to www.bsap.org with IE 11 and see the noticeboard...  Works well with Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Would appreciate a little fix which is not too complicated and preferably does not involve long scripts...

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you don't have any CSS rule which applies to Internet Explorer, only the vendor-prefixed versions for Firefox and Webkit-based browsers.

Just add:

```
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 15px;
column-rule-color: #888;
column-rule-style: solid;
column-rule-width: 1px;
```

... and it should work. (In IE 10+)

Comment: Thank you!  Clearly couldn't see the wood for the trees there... Much appreciate the nod!